# How do you send part of a command to vim(in Ex mode) using if_py?

Tags: python, vim

I'm trying to open a file on **Ctrl-f**. If the command is
typed in the presence of an empty buffer **'None'** then I
want the file to be opened in that buffer, but if there
is no empty buffer I'd like to open a new buffer using
**:tabnew** and then open the file in that.
For this purpose I have a function **OpenFile** which is 
invoked.

```
function! OpenFile()
python << EOF
import vim
import re
buffer = vim.current.buffer
name = str(buffer.name)
if re.match('None', name):
    vim.command(':e ')
else:
    vim.command(':tabnew')
    vim.command(':e ')
EOF
endfunction

"Open file
 :map <C-f> :call OpenFile()<CR> 
:imap <C-f> <Esc>:call OpenFile()<CR>
```

vim.command executes the command so this is equivalent to
:w!ENTER What I want to do is setup part of the command..
:e FILENAME ENTER

So I want to send the :e part in Ex mode via the
python-function and get the user to type the filename
and hit ENTER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why do you write this in Python? Sure, Vimscript is a bit strange (but since Vim 7 is has become a lot like Python), and you need to learn about the integration points, anyway, and this task has very little real logic in it.

This is easiest solved via a map-expression (`:help map-expression`):

```
:noremap <expr> <C-f> empty(bufname('')) ? ':edit ' : ':tabnew '
```

If you must, extract the conditional into a function and code it in Python, but I would recommend sticking to Vimscript, unless the logic is really complex or you could benefit from certain libraries.

Comment: number of reasons: i'm learning python - don't want to get diverted into learning vimscript given that i once knew perl/expect/c/c++/fortran at varying degrees of expertise. i find it hard to use vim. i thought if_py was supposed to solve thi problem of using vimscript. the question is in a series of questions designed to help me get vim working to my taste whilst learning python. Thanks though!